# error: call of overloaded 'basic_ofstream(int)' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, ofstream

```
std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> out_stream(const std::string &fname)
{
  if (fname.length() > 0)
  {
    if ((fname.compare("stderr") == 0) || (fname.compare("cerr") == 0))
    {
      std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> p(&std::cerr, [](std::ostream*){});
      return p;
    }
    if ((fname.compare("stdout") == 0) || (fname.compare("cout") == 0))
    {
      std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> p(&std::cout, [](std::ostream*){});
      return p;
    }
    if ((fname.compare("null") == 0) || (fname.compare("/dev/null") == 0))
    {
      std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> p(new std::ofstream(0));//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
    std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> p(new std::ofstream(fname));
    io_utils_logger.log(utils::LogLevel::FILE, "opening a file ", fname, "\n");
    return p;
  }
  else
      {
    std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> p(new std::ostream(std::cout.rdbuf()));
    return p;
  }
}
```

In the above source code, in the marked line, `new std::ofstream(0)` is showing the following error:

```
error: call of overloaded 'basic_ofstream(int)' is ambiguous
         std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> p(new std::ofstream(0));
                                                           ^
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you expect this line to do?

Comment: A [mre] could actually be this one line only: `std::ofstream f(0);`. What is your intention constructing `ofstream` with `0` ? I.e. which `ofstream` ctor did you intent to invoke ?

Comment: @wohlstad, Honestly speaking. My predecessor wrote this code. I am given the code to debug. I studied lower intermediate C++ in 2004. So, I can't answer your question.

Comment: I don't see a ctor of `ofstream` that accepts an `int`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream. There are some other ctors that accept types that are convertible from int, which is why you get the ambiguity error.

Comment: `new ostream(nullptr)` is probably the right thing. Read the docs and then make an informed decision.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Long story short, there have been numerous modifications in the source code over the past eight years. Some codes are obsolete.

Comment: The code is just wrong. Here `0` is an old way to write `nullptr`. There used to be a single constructor taking a pointer, so the code compiled. Now there are two such constructors, so ambiguous. But a `nullptr` has *never* been the *correct* value for the parameter.